# Collections.sort is not sorting data

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I have a custom class called `Song` like this-

```
public class Song implements Parcelable {
private String mTitle;
private String mArtist;
private long mID;
private long albumID;

public Song(long id,String title, String artist,long albumId)
{
    this.mID=id;
    this.mTitle=title;
    this.mArtist=artist;
    this.albumID=albumId;
}

public long getAlbumID() {
    return albumID;
}

public void setAlbumID(long albumID) {
    this.albumID = albumID;
}

public long getID()
{
    return mID;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return mArtist;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setID(long mID) {
    this.mID = mID;
}

public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle=mTitle;
}

public void setArtist(String mArtist) {
    this.mArtist = mArtist;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(mTitle);
    parcel.writeString(mArtist);
    parcel.writeLong(mID);
    parcel.writeLong(albumID);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR=new Parcelable.Creator()
{
    public Song createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Song(in);
    }

    public Song[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Song[size];
    }
};
public Song(Parcel in)
{
    mTitle=in.readString();
    mArtist=in.readString();
    mID=in.readLong();
    albumID=in.readLong();

  }


}
```

and a `ArrayList<Song>`.

I want to sort the data alphabetically. I'm using-

```
Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
            return  (a.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getTitle()));
        }
    });
```

However, my data is still not sorted. The list starts with a song starting with "h", then one with "o" and then one with "s".

Comment: The list starts with a song starting with "h", then one with "o" and then one with "s". -- so, is it sorted already?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Sorry, as I did not mention that there are 4 "a" after the "s"

Comment: Not possible with right data...  Prolly you are sorting after collection is used...  also remember that " s" is before "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. I was fetching the `songList` in a `Thread` and sorting it outside the Thread. So, it was sorting the data before the Thread finished fetching the data. Moved the sort part inside the Thread and it worked.